# Explanation for extended phase 10 5 sets of 2 in the same color

Tags: phase-10

I play the extended phases in phase 10 with my friends and phase 29 is 5 sets of 2 in the same colo. we use the standard deck and there is usually 3-4 of us playing. Do we add in another deck since there are only 2 numbers of the same color in each color or do we just play normally? It seems extremely hard to get it because its so limited and I can't find anywhere an explanation for that phase. any thoughts?

Comment: Source for the "extended phases"?  Is this something official from Mattel or from somewhere else?

Comment: I've only seen the 20 phase variant on Board Game Geek.  https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1258/phase-10

Comment: i found them in wikifandom i believe it was.  this is where i found some of them. i can list the phases i have if you want.    https://www.pagat.com/invented/phase10_vars.html

Answer (score 1):

May not have been the original intent, but far more doable: "5 sets of 2, with one color shared between all the sets."

IE

R2G2
R3B3
R5G5
R7Y7
R9G9

would be a valid hand, since you have 5 sets of two and each set has a red card in it.

---

If it's the same set of rules as was linked above, #19 there is "19. 5 sets of 2 in same color - wild card color must match number color". The context on the site makes it clear they intended all 10 of the cards to be the same color. It does seem to be a bit restrictive, but note that the wild cards can smooth out the missing duplicate numbers.

Also, "Note: The above rules use Phase 10 cards with colored wild cards. In some newer decks all the wild cards are the same color. If playing with this type of deck, just disregard the restrictions on wild card colors."